# Exporting from .obj to .fbx source code

Tags: export

I dont know if this is the right place to ask..

For a programming assignment in school I need to find in the source code where the export is made to an FBX file. Do you have any idea to where I should start to look? I've built everything with Cmake(it does not compile without 500 errors) and got a Blender project open in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the FBX importer and exporter code in the addons folder:

Blender_Installation_Folder\Your_Blender_Version\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx

On my system it's here:
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.74\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx

[More about paths in blender in different operating systems](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html)

By the way, you don't need to compile from source to see this code's source, since this is a python script (you can just download and install an ordinary package for your operating system).

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to locate that the command for exporting is from an execute command in the init file inside that folder. Do you know how I can move up one step further? Specifically, I want to know where the parameter Context is coming from. What is calling init.execute(()

Comment: The ExportFBX class you see in the init file is a blender operator. Blender operators (that are the basis for most blender commands and functionality) have a certain structure, and when they are called, the exceute function is, well, executed. The *context* parameter to automatically transferred to the execute function, and includes various data about the environment from which the operators is called (scene, window, screen, and many other things).

More about operators from the official blender docs: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.Operator.html